# How can I do an htmldecode on a formview or other ASP control?

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, formview, html-encode

I have a form with an asp textbox that has TinyMCE in it. This encodes the user's markup just fine, but when I click Update on the form, the FormView control needs to do a *decode* as it retrieves that record.

I can't figure out how to insert a Server.HtmlDecode into the process. Tips and references would be most welcome.